# The difference between const string& and string& without the const

Tags: c++, vector, constants, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I wrote a code to calculate the scalar product of two vectors. I can't seem to fully understand the passing by reference and the const. When i put in paramters of the void entervalues function a void entervalues(string& vect, vector& vectt); WITHOUT the const, it doesnt compile. When i put void entervalues(const string& vect, vector& vectt); WITH the const before the string, it compiles. Why is this? And why is it better to put the &. why can't i just put void entervalues( string vect, vector vectt); ?

My code is :

```
void entervalues(const string& vect, vector<double>& vectt);
double scalar(vector<double> u, vector<double> v);

double ask_number(int N_MAX){
    int n;
    do{ cout << "Enter a size for the vectors between 1 and " << N_MAX << endl;
        cin >> n; }while((n < 1) or (n > N_MAX));
    return n;
}

int main(){

    vector<double> U(ask_number(20));
    vector<double> V(ask_number(20));

    entervalues("First ", U);
    entervalues("Second ", V);
    cout << "Scalar product is  " << scalar(U,V) << endl;

    return 0;
}

double scalar(vector<double> u, vector<double> v){
    double sum(0.0);
    for(size_t i(0); i < u.size(); ++i){
        sum = sum + u[i]*v[i];}
    return sum;
}

void entervalues(const string& vect, vector<double>& vectt){
    cout << vect << "vecteur: " << endl;
    for(size_t i(0); i < vectt.size(); ++i){
        cout << "Coordonates: " << i+1 << endl;
        cin >> vectt[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"First "` is a string literal. When a `std::string` is constructed from that string literal (in order for your function to be called), the result is a temporary, and temporaries cannot be bound to non-`const` references.

As for passing the vectors by reference, you *can* pass a copy instead if you like (since you have no intention of modifying them within the function), but that copy is a needless waste of CPU time and of memory! I would in fact pass the vectors as `const std::vector&` so that you *enforce* not being able to modify them within a function that's not supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

The strings "First" & "Second" are constants.... The string objects constructed from them are temporaries, their values cannot be modified, therfore you can't pass them to a method that takes a non-constant reference.

If you don't pass the vectors by reference, then your enter values method will take a copy, and the vectors U & V passed to entervalues() will be unchanged.

Comment: +-1: That's not correct. The string literals would _never_ be modified anyway, since it's a [mutable] `std::string` that must be constructed from them in order for the function call to take place. That is, the function does not take `char*` or `const char*`. Finally, `scalar` doesn't modify `u` or `v` so your reasoning about that is wrong too.

Comment: Sorry, I meant entervalues() obviously, as scalar () doesn't take values by reference anyway. My point about the string objects passed to the function by using       string literals is valid, if simplistic... updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: It was completely wrong. You've now replaced your point with the totally different, correct point, which I wrote in my answer 21 hours ago. :)

Comment: Indeed, but talking of wrong, you said: "you can pass a copy instead if you like (since you have no intention of modifying them within the function)" ... talking about entervalues (), the entire purpose of which is to populate the vectors which are then passed to scalar () ;-)

Comment: Yep. You'll see I since deleted that answer. Either I misread the question or it used to refer to `scalar` in that passage. Mobile app's not showing me the rev history to check :(